# Host key verification failed on jenkins

Tags: jenkins

Context: I am running a shell script on a remote machine through Jenkins. But while running I am getting "Host key verification failed." error on Jenkins log.

code snippet

```
#!/bin/sh
#Shell script for running the script from jenkin
#Performance Engineering Team
triggerPerformanceTest(){
echo "Starting the Jmeter script"
ssh -tt -i Test.ppk ubuntu@testserver << EOF
cd apache-jmeter-3.1/bin/
JVM_ARGS="-Xms512m -Xmx25000m" ./jmeter.sh -n -t /home/ubuntu/JMeter/Test.jmx
exit
EOF
echo "Test successfully executed"
}

triggerPerformanceTest
```

I can run the same query from my local machine through code editor(refer the screenshot attached).[image]

Could some help me to resolve this issue? *Note: I cannot access to Jenkins server so not able to do anything there.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your remote machine key is not known by Jenkins. It's not present in `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file.

This is a security to prevent man-in-the-middle attacks.

Someone has to add it for you or you will not be able to ssh to the remote machine.

Comment: Thanks Zak. This makes sense as well.